# C# Save File at Location of Your App

Tags: c#, filestream, streamwriter

I am trying to save to a file like this:

```
    string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
    fs = new System.IO.FileStream(path, System.IO.FileMode.Append, System.IO.FileAccess.Write);
```

but I am getting DirectoryNotFoundException although directory exists.

Here is the method

```
public static void WriteToFile(string s)
{
    string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
    fs = new System.IO.FileStream(path, System.IO.FileMode.Append, System.IO.FileAccess.Write);
    sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(fs);
    sw.WriteLine(s);
    sw.Flush();
    sw.Close();
    fs.Close();
}
```

I am not sure why is this happening.  Thanks

Comment: There is very good chance that `path` points to directory (around 100%). Could you please clarify why you expect file creation to succeed for path to a directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify a **File Name**, the **Directory** alone in not enough to create a file:

```
public static void WriteToFile(string s, string fileName)
{
    string path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, fileName);
    fs = new System.IO.FileStream(path, System.IO.FileMode.Append, System.IO.FileAccess.Write);
    sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(fs);
    sw.WriteLine(s);
    sw.Flush();
    sw.Close();
    fs.Close();
}
```

**Usage:**

```
WriteToFile("Some Text To Write", "SampleFileName.txt");
```

Here is the documentation of:

```
public FileStream(string path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access);
```

> Parameters: 
>   path: A relative or absolute path for the file that the current FileStream object will encapsulate.

Answer (score 2):

Your' path is a directory, but *System.IO.FileStream.FileStream(string path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access)* expects a file path, so i modify your code like below:

```
public static void WriteToFile(string s)
    {
        string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "a.txt";
        var fs = new System.IO.FileStream(path, System.IO.FileMode.Append, System.IO.FileAccess.Write);
        var sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(fs);
        sw.WriteLine(s);
        sw.Flush();
        sw.Close();
        fs.Close();
        Console.WriteLine(path);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

output:
d:\users\zwguo\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleApplication15\Consol
eApplication15\bin\Debug\a.txt

Comment: You should concat path parts always with `Path.Combine`